# Как нажать на софт-клавишу c помощью Appium Capybara Ruby?

Tags: android, ruby, test-automation

Нужно нажать на софт-клавишу на Андроид эмуляторе.

"Такой степ", все что закомментировано, тоже не получается:

```
def tap_back_button
  # page.driver.press_keycode 4
  # input keyevent 4
  page.driver.navigate.back
  # Appium::Capybara::Driver.back
  # driver.execute_script 'mobile: keyevent', 4
  # Appium.back
  # system('adb shell input keyevent 4')
  # TouchAction().tap(4).perform()
  # key_event 4
  # Appium.press_keycode 4
  # press_keycode 4
  # Capybara.default_driver.back
end
```

Появляется ошибка:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `navigate' for #

Возможно, я как-то не так объявил драйвер в *env.rb* файле:

```
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/../lib'

ENVIRONMENT = (ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] || 'production').to_sym
raise "You need to create a configuration file named '#{ENVIRONMENT}.yml' under lib/config" unless File.exists? "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../lib/config/#{ENVIRONMENT}.yml"
<code>
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'site_prism'
require 'rspec'
require 'faker'
require 'env_config'
require 'jinfu'
require 'screens'
require 'common_helper'
require 'support/string'
require 'capybara_helper'
require 'active_support/all'
require 'appium_capybara'
require 'appium_lib'


World(Appium)
World(CommonHelper)
World(CapybaraHelper)

Capybara.register_driver :appium do |app|

    opts = Appium.load_appium_txt file: File.join("#{Dir.pwd}/lib/android", 'appium.txt')
    Appium::Capybara::Driver.new app, opts
end

Capybara.default_driver = :appium

SitePrism.configure do |config|
  config.use_implicit_waits = EnvConfig.get :use_implicit_waits

end
```

Answer (score 0):

ответ на мой ворос

в env.rb прописываем

`$capy_driver = Capybara.current_session.driver`

и юзаем в степе

```
  $capy_driver.go_back
```

но я так понял можно и таким методом

`$capy_driver.appium_driver.press_keycode 4`